# Scala: Passing instance of child class to parent class function

Tags: class, function, scala, parent

Why does the Scala repl say:

```
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;  
 found   : Car#Door  
 required: _1.Door where val _1: Car
```

When I run this statement:

```
var c = New Car  
c.is_door_open(c.door)
```

That refers to this class:

```
class Car {  
    var door = new Door(true)  

    class Door (var state: Boolean = true) {  }    

    def is_door_open(d: Door) {  
         println(d.state)  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Which Scala version? Works (after removing `= true` default value) on 2.7.7final...

Comment: Scala version is 2.9.0.1

Comment: @Tomasz : I suspect that out of (good) habit, you declared a val c rather than var c

Answer (score 6):

When you have an inner class as `Door` here, each *instance* of class `Car` defines a different `Door` type. In is_door_open(d: `Door`), Door means a Door of the enclosing instance of Car. The type Car#Door in the error message means a Door of any Car, it is the common type to all doors.

When you call `c.is_door_open(c.door)` the `Car` of `c.door` must be the same as the the `c` of `c.is_door_open`, as that is what the declaration of `is_door_open` requires (it should have been `d: Car#Door` otherwise). And moreover, they must be the same to the satisfaction of the compiler, which has some precise rules for that. Here it seems obvious the `cars` are the same. Not so, because `c` is a `var`, so not a stable identifier.

Imagine the code `c.is_door_open({c = new Car; c.door})`. Contrived of course, but this shows that you cannot rely on both occurence of c being the same car.

So among your solutions, depending of what your real code may be :

1. Make `c` a `val` instead of a `var`
2. declare `is_door_open` parameter as d: Car#Door
3. Stop making `Door` dependant on instance of `Car`, declare it outside the class, if you want it to be `Car.Door`, put it in a companion `object Car` rather than in `class Car`
4. Make `is_door_open` a method of `Door` (without a `Door` argument then) rather than Car. It has full access to the enclosing Car (with `Car.this` as in java, or declaring an alias for this in Car with `class Car {car =>` )

Comment: Thank you for the help. Now I get what Scala means when it uses the # symbol.